# How to automatically import WSDL which created by JDeveloper to OSB?

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, jdeveloper, osb

anybody can help me how do I can automatically register WSDLs which created by JDeveloper into OSB?
simply I wanna created some WSDL by using create web service wizard option in JDEV and automatically register those WSDL along their XSD files into OSB.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can automatically import WSDLs into an OSB Project.

For example, if you use Eclipse plugin for OSB then you need to manually go through the Import Resource to import WSDLs and use them when defining new Proxy/Business services.

I cannot imagine a use case where you would need this feature anyway. Do you know of any?